# How to see when a file/directory was first created and by what software/user?

Tags: windows-7

- I was wondering if there is a way to
  see when a file/directory was first
  created and by what software/user,
  under Windows 7?
- I have a strange file "test.log"
  right under C:, with its content
  being "1" and then return and
  newline. I was wondering if I can
  just delete it. But may want to see
  when and who first created it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a NTFS filesystem, each file both a *creation timestamp* and an *owner*, assigned at time of creation.

```
dir/q/tc C:\test.log
```

should display both.

Comment: Thanks! Is the owner of a file always its creator? Will it be able to change?

Comment: Is there a creation timestamp for a file in Linux? How to get it?

Comment: @Tim: Some filesystems (ntfs, ext4, maybe others) have creation timestamps, but there isn't yet a standard way of reading them.

Answer (score 3):

You **can't see who created** the file, it would be by one of the accounts that has permission over it.
You **can see the creation date** of the file in it's properties (right click on the file, cilck propertios).

Using [**Process Monitor**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can allow you to log who creates/accesses specific files.
You can just delete the `test.log` file and then figure out with Process Monitor who creates it...

Answer (score 2):

There's no obvious way to see who created it, since it would have required administrative rights (whether upon first install or during the course of the application's lifetime) to write to that location.

That said, it's a log file and completely harmless. If it was an `EXE` or `COM` or `BAT`, I'd be more concerned. It's probably a legacy application that writes to `C:\` because it's not compatible with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do `ls -l` but I believe you need to install Cygwin.
More information can be found here for installation:
http://www.askstudent.com/tips/how-to-use-unixlinux-commands-at-the-windows-command-prompt/